# Why are urls usually lowercase with words separated by a dash and no special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, uri

As an example, the Rails `parameterize` method would create a string like so:

"hello-there-joe-smith" == "Hello There Joe.Smith".parameterize

For legacy reasons, a project I am working on requires uppercase letters as well as periods to be available in a particular URL parameter.

Why would this ever be a problem?

#### Clarification

The url type I'm talking about is what is used instead of an id, commonly knows as a slug.

Would a Rails app with the following url come to any issues: `http://example.com/Smith.Joe`?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. (It's a question about URI and protocols, and there is no code-related question here. Using Ruby has nothing to do with the question you're asking, which isn't related to Ruby.)

Comment: Hi Ken, then please provide constructive criticism. As in, make a suggestion about what to do, not only what not to do.

Comment: My constructive criticism is a) Delete your previous rude comment, and b) ask on-topic (programming) questions here. Just because you don't know where else to ask doesn't mean you should post here. :) You might try asking at [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), or by searching this site or Google (try "URI encoding" or "URL encoding"). Try [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for starters; it has related links at the bottom also that might help.

Comment: I don't feel that my question is off-topic. It relates to web application development, particularly Rails, but yes, it is also open to general comments. And it has to do with programming because generating proper URI's and knowing how and why to do so, is relevant to programmers. If you wish to revise your original comment to include the constructive criticism, I will consider deleting my comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, Victor. Whether or not you think your post is off-topic, I do, and have voted to close it as such. My vote has been cast, and I can't take it back at this point no matter how hard you try to convince me to do so. :) If you read the FAQ (I already linked to it earlier), you'll see that's (in part) how SO works. (And thanks. :))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm not talking about url encoding but mostly wondering why there is a convention to having lowecase words separated by a dash, and what would, if any problems arise in a framework like Rails, if these conventions were not followed, I have updated my question to be clearer about this.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a problem both in terms of SEO and browser caching (and hence performance,)

1. Search engines are case sensitive, so same URL in different case will be taken as two URLs.
2. Browser like IE's caching is case sensitive, so eg. if you try to access your page as MYPAGE.aspx and at some place in code, you write it as mypage.aspx then IE will treat them as two different pages and instead of getting it from cahce, it will get it from server.
3. Dashes should be fine but underscores should be avoided : http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/